# Hybris ModelService remove not removing

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I'm trying to remove all the Stock from query products in a cronjob:

```
List<ProductModel> products = flexibleSearchService.search(GET_SPECIAL_PRODUCTS_QUERY);

for (ProductModel product : products.getResult()) {
     modelService.removeAll(product.getStockLevels());
}
```

If I debug here I can see that all the products have stock, however, after performing the removeAll method from model Service, the Stock is not removed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: maybe you just need to refresh product model after removing stock level models

Comment: if this is performed from groovy console "commit" mode has to be selected

Comment: as per above snippet, you are having search result in products variable but you are referring dufryProducts.getResult()

Comment: Have you tried to do `modelService.save(product)` after removing the stock?

Comment: Products will be available in different catalog versions. Try giving the proper catalog version in the query for deleting. Also, as mentioned by @RaushanKumar, flexible search returns SearchResult and getResult() method returns List<ProductModel>. In the above code, the return type of flexible query is wrong.